# No cookies axios React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm building React app and making requests to my backend server with axios. On the server side I'm sending a response with cookie but on the client side there is no "Set-Cookie" header in response.
I configured axios to use credentials:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api";

const api = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: API_URL
});

export default api;
```

And configured express app to use CORS with proper options on the backend:

```
...
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
...
```

Here is a Log in function on the server:

```
async logIn(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user_data = await userService.logIn(email, password);

        res.cookie('refresh_token', user_data.refresh_token, { maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true })
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Logged in successfully', ...user_data });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
}
```

And here is request from the client:

```
async logIn(email: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const response = await AuthService.logIn(email, password);
        console.log(response.headers["set-cookie"]); // undefined
        localStorage.setItem("_access_token", response.data.access_token);
        this.setAuth(true);
        this.setUser(response.data.user_dto);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

When I'm testing the log in endpoint with Postman everything is alright and I can see the cookie:
[image: Cookie]

Comment: how you send the cookie ? res.header("Set-Cookie","value") or what ?

Comment: `res.cookie('cookie', value)`

Comment: are you sure from the logic before do the res.cookie ? try to do this func alone to sure the problem in set cookie not in logic & if not try use res.setHeader("Set-Cookie","value")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. Just opened React app on `127.0.0.1:3000` instead of `localhost:3000` and set the same url to the "origin" in CORS options, than cookie was successfully saved in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract cookie(s) from an incoming request as such (`req.cookies`):

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.cookies);
  res.send();
});
```

Docs http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html

Comment: I can't access cookie on the client despite I set it to the response on the server `res.cookie('cookie', value)`

Answer (score 0):

accordance with the Fetch standard, client code cannot read Set-Cookie response headers, even if the server happens to be configured for CORS and lists Set-Header in its responses `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

Comment: I can't see the cookie in my browser too